# How to add PHP code to only a certain page in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have added styling to my anchor tag and have made the text-decoration to none to the entire website. But I want the blog section of my website to underline the links.

I'm using the code snippet plugin in wordpress as I don't have direct access to the files.

And this is the code that I'm using.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function  () { ?>
    <style>
        
         a:link {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
</style>
<?php } );
```

The problem is that this PHP code gets applied to my entire website which is not what I want. I only want this to be applied to the body section of the blog content.

I would love to have someone assist me with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: depends on your website but by default (if the theme is following wordpress standards) in your body you will have class blog and from there target specific element for example body.blog a:link { text-decoration: underline; } . That will target all anchors in body. You can even go with more specifict selection by adding other unique classes to the rule. As for the articles you should have single-post class.

Comment: You can get information about the current page using `global $page;` and then access properties of `$page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for CSS (inside a `<style>` tag) with specific selectors. Your CSS  selector, `a:link` is very non-specific. That is, the browser uses it whenever it sees an anchor `<a>` tag.

You need the browser to use it only on some anchor tags. So, you use a more specific selector.

Try using this CSS to style the links within articles in your posts and pages.

```css
div.site-content main article a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

It affects anchor tags only in html nested inside a hierarchy of HTML elements. Most themes use these elements.

If you want to style just posts (not pages), put `article.post` in the selector instead.

```css
div.site-content main article.post a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You can add CSS to your site without the Code Snippets plugin, and without php code.  Go to Appearance -> Customize. At the bottom of the left column choose Additional CSS. Then put in the CSS you need.

If you want to be able to figure this out for yourself, right-click in the browser element you want to style and choose Inspect. You'll see the HTML for that element along with the elements it's nested inside.

Additional CSS is a good setup because it survives plugin updates, and because you don't neet to hack any php to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. I changed it, in the additional CSS section itself.